# DRY Form Processing on Different Controllers in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, parameters, dry, controllers

I have two forms/views which share similar input parameters; but each view is supposed to be processed by a separate controller because additional logic unique to each view is required. Each controller has plenty of input parameters associated with it. What is the best practice?

I know this question may sound like the "Sharing variables between controllers" thing; But if i use the before_filter method; I have to declare every input parameter from the form again. If I define a new method in the parent application controller or create a helper method for input parameter extraction; other methods in the child controller cannot access the variables... Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you define a method in Application Controller, its variables **are** accessible. I've been having a method define @current_user across controllers without mishap, as long as the before_action is declared in each controller.

Answer (score 1):

I often find cases where I need some reusable business logic outside of a controller. In those cases I'll define a new object in my /lib folder so I can use it multiple places. For example,

```
# lib/my_business_logic/do_stuff.rb
module MyBusinessLogic
    class DoStuff
        def self.dostuff(params)
           # do stuff
        end
     end
end
```

Then I can call:

```
result = MyBusinessLogic::DoStuff.dostuff(params)
```